# Linode ignores .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, linode

This is my .htaccess (wordpress site) on a linode instance. It does not work even when I try to break it.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress 

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: It definitely works on Linode as I have several servers with them. They are just regular linux servers.  It's your setup. Do as Jon Lin is suggesting to see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the `AllowOverride` directive setup for the directory (or document root) that your htaccess file is in.

For example, if your htaccess file is in `/var/www/htdocs/` then make sure your vhost config has something like:

```
<Directory "/var/www/htdocs">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Or at the very least, that directive for a parent directory. I think at the very least you'll need `FileInfo` if you don't want to turn on all override options:

```
<Directory "/var/www/htdocs">
    AllowOverride FileInfo
</Directory>
```